# Table checking for text length in verifyText

Tags: java, swt, verify

I'm having some issues regarding the textlength in my swt Table. I'd like to check the length of the text when its entered and stop the user from being able to commit anymore, when the max number of letters is reached.

I'm not sure if I should do this in the verifyText method or if there is some other way. Hope you can give me a hint on how to handle this.

```
@Override
public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) { 
    if (/*checktextlength*/) {
        e.doit = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah didn't think of that one. I just found out I could also just set the TextLimit of my TextCellEditor

```
TextCellEditor textEditHex3Digit = new TextCellEditor(SendTab);
    ((Text) textEditHex3Digit.getControl()).setTextLimit(1);
```

Is there a difference between your and my approach?

Comment: Don't know, haven't used a `TextCellEditor` so far. I didn't read the question properly and assumed you were working with a `Text` widget. If your solution works, this seems to be the cleaner way of doing it.